# node.js callback function at the after loop has ended

Tags: node.js

I have an array of URLs and I want to loop through them and fetch thr content. After I have looped through them and fetched thr content I want a callback function to be called.

I know I can do this via async library but I want to do this without using any library.
Sample of what kind of code I want is below

```
['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com'].each(function(item){
//code to fetch URL content
},someCallbackFunctionToBeExecutedAtTheEndOfLoop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without any sort of library like async, then you have to write your own counter to keep track of when all the async responses have been completed:

```
var request = require('request');

function loadAll(list, fn) {
    var cnt = list.length;
    var responses = [];

    list.forEach(function(url, index) {
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                fn(error);
            } else {
                responses[index] = response;
                --cnt;
                if (cnt === 0) {
                    fn(0, responses);
                }
            }
        });
    })

}


loadAll(['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.gmail.com'], function(err, results) {
    if (!err) {
        // process results array here
    }
});
```

---

If you're going to be doing many async operations in node.js, then getting a promise library like Bluebird will save you a lot of time.  For example, I think you could do the above in something like this (untested):

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var requestP = Promise.promisfy(require("request"));

Promise.map(['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.gmail.com'], requestP).then(function(results) {
    // process the array of results here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is typically the type of thing you do using promises (But you would need a library), with a code like:

```
var ops = [];
urls.forEach(function(url) {
    ops.push(fetchUrl(url));
});
P.all(ops).then(callback);

function fetchUrl(url) {
    var defer = P.defer();
    //do stuff
    // call defer.resolve(result);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

If you don't want to use promises, you can use a counter of operations, like:

```
var ops = urls.length;
urls.forEach(function(url) {
    // do stuff
    ops--;
    if (ops === 0) {
        callback();
    }
});
```

If you chose the promises, I advice to use p-promise module, which is far more optimized than Q.